# how to add pause/play button to notification in Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

I have service which plays the radio & creates a notification. The notification must incude title, text, time & a button(pause/play). I have added rest of the things & notification is getting displayed. But I'm not sure about how to add the button to the notification. On searching, I found I can use RemoteView, RemoteControlClient & MediaStyles. But  RemoteControlClient & MediaStyles are used when there is a media file playing with all buttons(previous,pause,play,back). So I'm really confused about it. Can anyone suggest me, which one to use to add buttons in the notification for Lollypop.

Comment: use remote views and follow the link  http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-custom-notification-tutorial/

Comment: Will it work for Lollypop?

Comment: recently we implemented notification in one application with remote views.Its working fine in lollipop also

Comment: use custom notification with remote views - http://www.skholingua.com/android-basic/advance-topics/notifications

Comment: Okay..I'll use it..& let u know if it works

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know `addAction` is deprecated in 23 API, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35647894/7569106) to relate

Call `showNotification()` method to show notification

```
 private void showActionButtonsNotification() {


        Notification.Builder notif;
        NotificationManager nm;
        notif = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        notif.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notif.setContentTitle("Hi there!");
        notif.setContentText("This is even more text.");
        Uri path = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        notif.setSound(path);
        nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent yesReceive = new Intent();
        yesReceive.setAction(MyNotificationReceiver.RESUME_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentYes = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, MyNotificationReceiver.REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION, yesReceive, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notif.addAction(R.drawable.resume, "resume", pendingIntentYes);


        Intent yesReceive2 = new Intent();
        yesReceive2.setAction(MyNotificationReceiver.STOP_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentYes2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, MyNotificationReceiver.REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION, yesReceive2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notif.addAction(R.drawable.stop, "stop", pendingIntentYes2);




        Intent maybeReceive2 = new Intent();
        maybeReceive2.setAction(MyNotificationReceiver.CANCEL_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentMaybe2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, MyNotificationReceiver.REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION, maybeReceive2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notif.addAction(R.drawable.cancel, "cancel", pendingIntentMaybe2);


        assert nm != null;
        nm.notify(MyNotificationReceiver.REQUEST_CODE, notif.getNotification());


    }
```

Create `MyNotificationReceiver` class to recive the clicks

```
    public class MyNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public static int REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION = 1212;
        public static int REQUEST_CODE = 10;
        public static final String RESUME_ACTION = "RESUME_ACTION";
        public static final String STOP_ACTION = "STOP_ACTION";
        public static final String CANCEL_ACTION = "CANCEL_ACTION";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            Log.e("action", action);

            if (intent.getAction() != null) {
                switch (intent.getAction()) {
                    case RESUME_ACTION :
                        Toast.makeText(context, "resume", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// you resume action
                        break;
                    case STOP_ACTION :
                        Toast.makeText(context, "stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// you stop action
                        break;
                    case CANCEL_ACTION:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// you cancel action
                        break;
                }
            }
        }



    }
```

Finally, add `receiver` to your `manifests`

```
<receiver android:name=".MyNotificationReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="RESUME_ACTION"/>
                <action android:name="STOP_ACTION"/>
                <action android:name="CANCEL_ACTION"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```