# Android notification .addAction deprecated in api 23

Tags: android

What is the proper way to add an action to the notification in `API 23` since `addAction(int icon, CharSequence title, PendingIntent intent)` is deprecated ? Couldn't find any example, thank you.

My old action: `.addAction(R.drawable.ic_prev, "Previous", prevPendingIntent)`

Comment: According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#addAction%28android.app.Notification.Action%29), you should use `addAction (Notification.Action action)` instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852270/how-to-implement-the-deprecated-methods-of-notification

Comment: I already looked at that example @sasikumar, it doesn't help me, I don't understand how to build the `Notification.Action action`

Answer (score 25):

Instead of this one:

> [addAction (int icon, CharSequence title, PendingIntent intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#addAction%28int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)
>
> **This method was deprecated in API level 23.**

Use:

> [addAction (Notification.Action action)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#addAction%28android.app.Notification.Action%29)

It's all in the developer docs!

So to use this:

first build your action with the [NotificationCompat.Action.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Action.Builder.html)

```
NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_prev, "Previous", prevPendingIntent).build();
```

**Note:** Use [NotificationCompat.Action](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Action.html)

And than add it to your notification:

```
yournotification.addAction(action);
```

Comment: I know, I already read it, but I don't understand how to proper build the  `Notification.Action action`

Comment: This is incorrect, incompatible types, you need to change `new Notification.Action.Builder()` to `new Action()` and the result: `new Notification.Action(.....)` is still deprecated or vice versa which is still deprecated.

Comment: For this to work use 'new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)'

Comment: `Notification.Action` doesn't seem to be deprecated.

Comment: Hi, can we add colored icons in add action , becuse it is turning colored icon into grey color

Answer (score 16):

Use [`Icon`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Icon.html) class at first parameter for Drawable **if api level >= 23(marshmallow)**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Action.Builder.html

https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/android.app.Notification.Action.Builder.html

example)

```
Notification.Action action = new Notification.Action.Builder(
    Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.ic_prev),
    "action string",
    pendingIntent).build();
```

Comment: Old question but still need it :) going to test it today and I will come with an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
//Exemple of notification with Button
private void scheduleNotificationWithButton(String message) {

    int notifReCode = 1;

    //What happen when you will click on button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    //Button
    NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Go", pendingIntent).build();

    //Notification
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentText("Back to Application ?")
            .setContentTitle("Amazing news")
            .addAction(action) //add buton
            .build();

    //Send notification
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to use NotificationCompat.Builder builder in place of Notification.Builder builder because NotificationCompat.Builder allows you to build your application below Android Version 4.1

Solved by using NotificationCompat.builder:

```
    String strTitle = getString(R.string.new_message);
    String strText = getString(R.string.hi_whats_up);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationView.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", strTitle);
    intent.putExtra("text", strText);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
           .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
           .setTicker("Notification Ticker")
           .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
           .setContentText("Notification Text")
           .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Notification Action", pendingIntent)
           .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
           .setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
           notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Comment: This works great for me.  Seems redundant for android to have so many ways to create a stupid notification?

Answer (score 1):

```
Actually, the only option to use all non-deprecated methods is by Using Icon for Action.Builder.

    
Notification.Action action = new Notification.Action.Builder(Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.act_hike), 
getString(R.string.finish_recording), pActionFinish).build();

//Create a notification
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.atlas)
.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
.setContentText(getString(R.string.foreground_notification))
.addAction(action)
.setContentIntent(pIntent)
.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use special builder [Notification.Action.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Action.Builder).

```
    Notification.Action.Builder builder = new Notification.Action.Builder( Icon.createWithResource( this, R.drawable.ic_pause), getString( R.string.pause ), PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 1, new Intent( TIMER_PAUSE ), 0 ) );
    Notification.Action action = builder.build();
...
    notification_builder.addAction( action ); // or setActions( action );
```