# How to cancel IntentService from Notification?

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I have a service which basically loops from 0-9 and sleeps 1000 for each loop. This service also creates a notification which shows the progress. I wanted to add some action which allows me to cancel the service. I have the following codes but it doesn't seem to work.

I've come up with this following from the following:

[Android Jelly Bean notifications with actions](https://shashikawlp.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/android-jelly-bean-notifications-with-actions/)

[Android notification .addAction deprecated in api 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647821/android-notification-addaction-deprecated-in-api-23)

```
public class FileOperationService extends IntentService {

    public FileOperationService() {
        super("FileOperationService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(this, CancelFileOperationReceiver.class);
        deleteIntent.putExtra("notification_id",1);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentCancel = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, deleteIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationManagerCompat manager = (NotificationManagerCompat.from(this));

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel, "Cancel", pendingIntentCancel).build();

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setContentText("In Progress");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.addAction(action);
        builder.setProgress(9, 0, false);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Log.d("Service", String.valueOf(i));
            builder.setProgress(9, i, false);

            if (i == 9) {
                builder.setContentTitle("Done");
                builder.setContentText("");
                builder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
                manager.notify(1, builder.build());
            } else {
                manager.notify(1, builder.build());
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}


public class CancelFileOperationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent();
        service.setComponent(new ComponentName(context, FileOperationService.class));
        context.stopService(service);
        NotificationManagerCompat manager = (NotificationManagerCompat.from(context));
        manager.cancel(intent.getIntExtra("notification_id",0));

        Log.d("Cancel","true");
    }

}
```

I can see that it cancels the notification because it closes each time I click Cancel. However, it doesn't seem to cancel the IntentService as a new notification pops up on each loop.

Answer (score 0):

IntentService automatically stops itself when onHandleIntent() ends, if no more commands had been sent to it while onHandleIntent() was running. Hence, you do not manually stop an IntentService yourself.

If you call stopSelf() then all Intents which are waiting in the IntentService queue are removed.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to prevent the service from moving forward. Like in my example. If I cancel during the 4th iteration, then I want the service to stop there.

Comment: Then you can blank "else if" block for which iteration you don't want to execute task. when iteration stop, service will stop automatically.