# Android - How to create a Notification with Action

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm creating a notification like this.

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
        builder.setContentTitle(notifyMessage1)
                .setContentText(notifyMessage2)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

Notification notification = builder.build();
```

I want to add a action to my notification with

```
builder.addAction();
```

To realize `addAction(icon, title, pendingIntent);` is deprecated

My geal is to create a notification action without an icon, how can i achieve that?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647821/android-notification-addaction-deprecated-in-api-23) may help .

Comment: okay, but how I don't want an icon.

Comment: i think you can pass `0` if you do not need icon . I am not sure of it .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the NotificationCompat instead of Notification like this:

```
Notification.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action(icon, title, pendingIntent);
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
       .addAction(action)
       .build();
```

Comment: isn't NotificationCompat also deprecated?

Comment: @braulio.cassule No its not.

Comment: It is now deprecated. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat

Comment: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat is deprecated, but androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat is not and is used extensively in the current documentation.

Answer (score 17):

You can't directly call methods when you click action buttons.

You require to use PendingIntent with BroadcastReceiver or Service to perform this.

Here is an example of Pending Intent with Broadcast Reciever.

**First build a Notification**

```
public static void createNotif(Context context){

...
//This is the intent of PendingIntent
Intent intentAction = new Intent(context,ActionReceiver.class);

//This is optional if you have more than one buttons and want to differentiate between two
intentAction.putExtra("action","actionName");

pIntentlogin = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,1,intentAction,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
drivingNotifBldr = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.steeringwheel)
        .setContentTitle("NoTextZone")
        .setContentText("Driving mode it ON!")
        //Using this action button I would like to call logTest
        .addAction(R.drawable.smallmanwalking, "Turn OFF driving mode", pIntentlogin)
        .setOngoing(true);
...
}
```

**Now the receiver which will receive this Intent**

```
public class ActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //Toast.makeText(context,"recieved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    String action=intent.getStringExtra("action");
    if(action.equals("action1")){
        performAction1();
    }
    else if(action.equals("action2")){
        performAction2();

    }
    //This is used to close the notification tray
    Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
    context.sendBroadcast(it);
}

public void performAction1(){

}

public void performAction2(){

}
}
```

**Do not forget to declare BroadCast Receiver in Manifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".ActionReceiver"></receiver>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I was having an issue getting Local broadcasters to receive data until I added it in the manifest file