# Nexus 7 tablet not showing notification actions

Tags: android, android-notifications, notification-action

I'm trying to show notifications actions on a Nexus 7 with Android 6.0.1 but it's not showing. Is it because of the OS? I have tested with a S6 edge with Android 7.0 and it looks perfect.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, resources.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .addAction(NotificationCompat.Action(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, resources.getString(R.string.confirm_action_notification), yesPendingIntent))
            .addAction(NotificationCompat.Action(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, resources.getString(R.string.deny_action_notification), noPendingIntent))
            .setPriority(PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setCustomHeadsUpContentView(headsUpView)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setCustomContentView(collapsedView)
            .setCustomBigContentView(expandedView)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setPublicVersion(privateNotification)
            .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code:

```
Notification n = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(violationHeader)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.login_logo)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(uri)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{10, 40, 100, 200, 10})
            .build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, n);
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve the problem. Your solution doesn't even add actions.

Comment: Please check the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647821/android-notification-addaction-deprecated-in-api-23/37134139#37134139

Comment: Thanks but it's not a solution because unfortunately Nexus 7 runs Marshmallow. I can't use the API Notification and Notification Action.